# How do I unlock additional songs in Wii Music's hand bell game?

Tags: wii-music

The UI for the handbell game pretty clearly is built to scroll and allow more songs, but I've only got 5 of them. What do I need to do to unlock more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there appear to only be [5 songs available](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/950924-wii-music/answers?qid=13564) for the handbell.

Comment: wow that's sad. Funnest game on there, drunk or sober.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of less of a game and more of a concept/demo in some ways :)